# How to escape an entity in FTP password specified in ANT target

Tags: ant, ftp

I'm trying to FTP a file to a server where the password contains an ampersand (&) via ANT
The following ANT target:

```
<target name="upload_zip">
    <ftp server="myhost.net"
         userid="myusername"
         password="topsecret&amp;"
         port="21"
         remotedir="/public_html"
         passive="yes"
         binary="yes">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="${updatefile}"   />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

Fails with this message:

```
error during FTP transfer:  java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: recv failed  
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)  
   at ... // really long stack trace
```

It looks like the authentication isn't successful. If I don't escape the ampersand, then my build file is not well formed. Am I escaping the ampersand correctly or doing something wrong?

Comment: Do an experiment first: put your password in a properties file (don't escape), and use this property in your ftp task.

Comment: Try a manual ftp, make sure it's not a file system permissions problem  with the transfer, rather than a connection credential problem.

Comment: @martin - manual ftp works fine, thanks.

Comment: @coolcfan that was a very good suggestion, but I am sad to report that putting the password unescaped in a properties file which I load and use, gives the same "permission denied" error :-(

Comment: @martin your hunch was correct it turned out to be a [Windows 7 firewall / netbeans issue] (http://forums.netbeans.org/post-115176.html#113923). Please post an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an obvious problem with the method you are using - the entity should be translated correctly.

To diagnose automated ftp it's probably best to try a similar (or identical!) transfer manually first.  Usually that will reveal any external issues with connection credentials or permissions in the target file system.

If a manual transfer works, then the next step would be to 'spot the difference' between the manual transfer and the Ant-driven one.

A stack trace for an ftp problem is probably indicative of a pre-connect issue - once you have a connection, you'll instead see an FTP error message, e.g.:

- *Could not login to FTP server*

That would probably indicate a problem with the login-password combination.

If the server is down you'll get a trace with something like:

- *java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused*

It seems though in your case it was a problem with an intermediate proxy.  For future readers, [this resource](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ftp_and_firewalls.html) may help in diagnosing passive ftp through firewall issues.

Failing all that, running Ant in verbose (`-v`) or diagnostic (`-diagnostics`) modes to see the innards of what Ant is doing may also give a clue.